# Wired (USB) support Via Sony SDK for A7R?

Tags: camera, sony

We are developing an aerial camera system using the A7R and were wondering about any software, SDKs, or other aids to allow us to collect images over the USB connection?

Thanks,

-Mark

Answer (score -3):

Please check discussions at [http://community.sony.com/](http://community.sony.com/t5/Cameras-Camcorders/ct-p/digital-still-cameras-camcorders%20%22http://community.sony.com) for more solutions.

Remote Camera Control Software by Sony [Link](http://www.sony-europe.com/support/en/content/cnt-dwnl/prd-dime/sony-remote-camera-control-ver33/SLT-A99#relevant_products) might come in handy for your situation.

Best Regards,
Prem, Developer World team at Sony